# python: Confusion with import

Tags: python

I am working on writing a python code and creating my own packages for ease. But getting confused.
My directory structure is like:

```
testing_validate.py
lib/
    conf.py
    logs.py
    validate_files/
        validate_tls_config_file.py
        __init__.py
```

Here, `testing_validate.py` goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

path = os.path.abspath('./lib')    #gets you absolute path of the library
sys.path.insert(0, path)        #you can insert that path(taken above) in the PATH variable of the system

import conf
conf.LOG_FILE_NAME = "/var/log/ConfigTLS.log"

from validate_files import validate_tls_config_file
#conf.LOG_FILE_NAME = "/var/log/ConfigTLS.log"

if validate_tls_config_file.validate_tls_config_file(conf.CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION) == False:
    print "Check log file for error: ", conf.LOG_FILE_NAME
```

Inside `conf.py`, I have:

```
LOG_FILE_NAME = ""
```

And inside `validate_tls_config_file.py`, I am performing some validations on some file. Contents:

```
import conf
from logs import *
import os

@log_procedure_call
def validate_tls_config_file(file_path):
```

Confusion is in the file `testing_validate.py`. Here, when I am using `conf.LOG_FILE_NAME = "/var/log/ConfigTLS.log"` after `import conf` and before `from validate_files import validate_tls_config_file`, the variable is getting initialized. But instead, if I am using `conf.LOG_FILE_NAME = "/var/log/ConfigTLS.log"` after `from validate_files import validate_tls_config_file` (shown as commented above), the variable's value is not reflected in `validate_tls_config_file`.

As per my understanding, this should work both ways. The variable is imported in `validate_tls_config_file.py` as well. So, any modifications before that function is called should be reflected. But why is this not happening?

Comment: I get your point, but another question also emerges: What is the rationale of changing a config during runtime? This is what evokes problems like the one you described: You want to handle its contents and changes to its local variables globally.

Comment: Actually the same logs.py will be used by multiple scripts to create different log files with different names. The `logs.py` is a generic module that I made for that purpose. So, that is why!